# Asterisk failing at startup after upgrading to asterisk18

Tags: asterisk, asterisknow

I was using asterisk16 and asterisk16-skypeforasterisk, which was working fine.

I have recently upgraded to asterisk18 and asterisk18-skypeforasterisk, after that I am
receiving the following error message.

Asterisk ended with exit status 1

Asterisk died with code 1.

Asterisk could not start!

Use 'tail /var/log/asterisk/full' to find out why.

When I checked the log I got the following messages.

codec_g729a.c:   == Found total of 11 G.729 licenses

translate.c: empty buf size, you need to supply one

Now, if I remove the /var/lib/asterisk/licenses folder it works fine.

Can you please tell me what could be the issue here ?

Warm Regards
Supratik

Comment: I am able to find the issue myself. The proper G729 codec was not
installed when installed through the RPM. Manually installing the
library file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you install the library file for the G729 codec manually - it may not get installed properly when doing the RPM.